# remove the last written line and replace it python

Tags: python

In order to create a progress bar that show the lode by present

The thinking behind it was to erase the line and then rewrite it so it will look like the current precent.

I tried to do this:

```
import time
---some kind of loop---:
    ... downloading stuff ...
    b = str((prhelp / 576)*100)
    print(b + "%", end="\r")
    time.sleep(1)
    prhelp = prhelp + 1
```

But it just don't printing any thing

Also I would like to know how to print a number only 3 digits after the dot - 
`12.345678` --> `12.345`

So my program won't print too long precent

Comment: your python code isn't valid...

Comment: `round(12.345678,3)` ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At the end I just needed to do:

```
import time
b = str(round((prhelp / 576) * 100,3))
print('\r',end = "")
print(b + "%",end = "")
time.sleep(0.01)
prhelp = prhelp + 1
```

By doing

```
print('\r',end = "")
```

I'm removing the last line and makeing place for the next number im writing.

Thanks for all the helpers

Answer (score 0):

it's because when you `print`, you give the parameter `end` is the string that will be added to the end. By default, it's `\n`. You gave `\r`. What this character means is *remove the current line*. That's why it doesn't print a thing...

If you want it to work, your replace this:

```
print(b + "%", end="\r")
```

by:

```
print(b + "%")
```

What I'm guessing you want is:

```
import time
print('Hello', end='')
time.sleep(1)
print('\rworld!')
```

This code will print `Hello`, wait 1 second, and then replace the `Hello` by `world!`

Comment: after a few seconds the result is
    world
    world
    world
    world
    hello

so it's not working...

Comment: \r is a carriage return, calling `print("stuff", end="\r")` means that you print "stuff" and tell the computer to write the next caracters over what's already there. So `print("stuff", end="\r"); print("ab", end="\r")` will show `abuff`

Comment: Try printing "Hello" and then "\rfai" using your code , "\r" does not erase the line.